# How can I make a batch action to copy files to google drive, php?

Tags: php, symfony, google-drive-api

For example: I can copy only one file but I need opportunity to copy a few files because I have problems with the speed of application.

```
        $fileMimeType = $this->service->files->get($googleFileId, array('fields' => 'mimeType'));
        $metadata = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(
            array(
                'name' => uniqid(),
                'uploadType' => 'multipart',
                'mimeType' => isset($fileMimeType->mimeType) ? $fileMimeType->mimeType : false
            )
        );

        $file = $this->service->files->copy($googleFileId, $metadata, array('fields' => 'id'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample from the docs of the google-api-client :

```
<?php
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
// Warn if the API key isn't set.
if (!$apiKey = getApiKey()) {
  echo missingApiKeyWarning();
  return;
}
$client->setDeveloperKey($apiKey);

$service = new Google_Service_Books($client);

$client->setUseBatch(true);

$batch = $service->createBatch();
$optParams = array('filter' => 'free-ebooks');
$req1 = $service->volumes->listVolumes('Henry David Thoreau', $optParams);
$batch->add($req1, "thoreau");
$req2 = $service->volumes->listVolumes('George Bernard Shaw', $optParams);
$batch->add($req2, "shaw");

$results = $batch->execute();
```

In your case, i think it will look like this :

P.S : Try enabling the batch processing when creating your client as show above (`$client->setUseBatch(true);`)

```
$batch = $this->service->createBatch();

$fileMimeType = $this->service->files->get($googleFileId, array('fields' => 'mimeType'));
$metadata = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(
   array(
     'name' => uniqid(),
     'uploadType' => 'multipart',
     'mimeType' => isset($fileMimeType->mimeType) ? $fileMimeType->mimeType : false
      )
     );

$fileCopy = $this->service->files->copy($googleFileId, $metadata, array('fields' => 'id'));

$batch->add($fileCopy, "copy");

$results = $batch->execute();
```

More details [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/batch.php)

Comment: Thanks, you forward me to one of solving :)

Answer (score 0):

Abdelkarim EL AMEL: Thanks, you forward me to one of solving :)

We can't use this code:

```
$fileCopy = $this->service->files->copy($googleFileId, $metadata, array('fields' => 'id'));

$batch->add($fileCopy, "copy");
```

Because method `$batch->add` accept `Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface`, `$this->service->files->copy` returned `Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile`

But we can create `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request` as same creating method copy from `$this->service->files->copy`.

This code solved my problem:

```
    private function copyFileRequest($googleFileId)
    {
        // build the service uri
        $url = $this->service->files->createRequestUri('files/{fileId}/copy', [
            'fileId' => [
                'location' => 'path',
                'type' => 'string',
                'value' => $googleFileId,
            ],
        ]);

        $request = new Request('POST', $url, ['content-type' => 'application/json']);

        return $request;
    }

    public function batchCopy()
    {
        $googleFileIdFirst = 'First file';
        $googleFileIdSecond  = 'Second file';

        $batch = $this->service->createBatch();

        $batch->add($this->copyFileRequest($googleFileIdFirst));
        $batch->add($this->copyFileRequest($googleFileIdSecond));

        $results = $batch->execute();

        /** @var Response $result */
        foreach ($results as  $result) {
            /** @var Stream $body */
            $body = (string)$result->getBody(); // Returned json body with copy file
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way, we can set `defer` as true for `Google_Client`

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE]);

// Calls should returned request not be executed
$client->setDefer(true)

$service = new \Google_Service_Drive($this->client);
```

And all methods from service return `Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface`

```
$batch = $service->createBatch();

$googleServiceDriveFile = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(['name' => uniqid()]);

$request = $service->files->copy($googleFileId, $googleServiceDriveFile, ['fields' => 'id']);

$batch->add($request);

$results = $batch->execute();
```